# How do I build Flutter application locally?

Tags: macos, flutter, build

I have developed (on a Mac) a small Flutter app to learn the technology. Now, I would like to build it and use it on Mac, Linux and Android. The few packages I have used claim compatibility with all systems.

So the first thing I did was to run `flutter build macos`. I indeed obtain an application under `build/macos/Build/Products/Release/nameofmyapp.app`. It seems this runs correctly, but it fails, for instance, loading data from a DB, which is the first thing it should do.

I have a few questions:

- are there any other steps that I should take? I see a long [guide](https://flutter.dev/docs/deployment/macos) about the release process, but to be frank I don't need or want any of that: I only want to use the app myself. Is there something else to do other than `flutter build macos`?
- am I looking for the built app in the right place?
- if I did everything correctly, could it be that I need to authorize the app to access to the file in some way? Should I manage this workflow myself, or is there a standard way to perform this action in Flutter?

Sorry for asking more than one question, but I am not sure whether what I am doing wrong is

- the build process
- where to look for the built app, or
- (not) handling the app permissions.

**EDIT**

Following a suggestion by Madhavam, I tried `flutter run --release`. The result is identical to running the built application: nothing is loaded from the database, and no errors appear in the console.

To be clear, these are the libraries that are not working:

- [sqflite](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite) should load data from a database (in my Documents folder) but does not show anything
- [file picker cross](https://pub.dev/packages/file_picker_cross) should allow me to load data from a JSON file, but when I try this interaction, I an not shown any dialog to load a file
- [shared preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) should read some settings, but they all appear as `null`

In short, anything that has to do with interacting with external files or storage does not seem to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it seems that this is related to the default being an app that runs in sandbox. Since I do not want to distribute the app, it was fine for me to disable this setting. Details are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67128763/flutter-macos-access-to-files)

Answer (score 1):

Yup, you have to manage it yourself. Take a look at this package
:https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

If you're using Firebase then you probably need to add the release keys.

One thing too, if you face an error only in the release build then I recommend running the app with `flutter run --release` so that you can see the errors that are being thrown.

Comment: Thank you. Following your suggestion, I tried running it in release mode, but I did not see any error. I am editing my question to add this piece of information

Comment: Oh, well i'm glad you were able to make it work later. Happy Coding!